# How to break line in a flex layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have my first, second, and third items and then I want the forth item to go to the next line no matter how wide is the space.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.it {
  max-width: 420px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="it">1</div>
  <div class="it">2</div>
  <div class="it">3</div>
  <div class="it">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd use grid over flex for this use case

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can insert a wide pseudo-element at the right position:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-container::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-item:last-child { /* or `:nth-child(n + 4)` */
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it almost works. The only problem is, if there is a 5th element, the 4th element goes to the next row, but the fifth element stays in the first row.

Comment: @kptlronyttcna Then use `:nth-child(n + 4)` instead of `:last-child`.

Comment: @kptlronyttcna Using pseudo-elements, you can only insert content in two different places (`::before` and `::after`), so can't have more than two forced line-breaks. However, you can edit the HTML layout and add wide dummy elements at the right places, as many as you want.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this by:

```
.flex-container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    /* how you want your lines */
    text-align:center;
}

<div class="flex-container">
    <p>Line1</p>
    <p>Line2</p>
</div>
```